# Quickest way to download HTML source run through a JS engine?

Tags: web-scraping

I'm looking for a quick way to download HTML from a URL. The page has to be processed by a JS engine first so `curl` won't cut it. I can do:

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome  --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom https://www.nytimes.com/`

But that is very slow (takes 5 seconds or more) as I suspect Chrome has a bunch of overhead.

I'd like to get something that works in under a second (assuming web server is fast).

Answer (score 0):

This little python package works great: https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/